# Wordpress - different logo on pages

Tags: php, wordpress

My theme has a black logo for home page and white logo for pages and posts. It shows a white logo as it expects a featured image on pages and posts and then the logo itself is visually good looking overlaying the image. 
This works great on posts (as I put a featured image on every post), but on pages I want to show a black logo, as I don't want any featured images.

I have put this code in my page.php file:

```
<?php 
if(is_page(3)) {
 get_header('BLACK');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>
```

In this case I created a header-black.php file for my page with ID 3. If the page is not ID 3 it just falls to the normal theme header. All good up to here, but now I have a dilemma:

What do I have to do if I want a header-black.php for my ID page 3, 4, 5 etc.? If I add the same code with different page ID below:

```
<?php 
if(is_page(3)) {
 get_header('BLACK');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>    

<?php 
if(is_page(4)) {
 get_header('BLACK');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>
```

it shows both logos on ID 4 page (the black AND the white)? The logo is still okay on the ID 3 page though. There will be only a few pages on my website (mostly posts) - just to point that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP "OR" Operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

```
<?php 
if ( is_page(3) || is_page(4) ) :
 get_header('BLACK');
else :
 get_header();
endif;
wp_head();
?>
```

You could also pass an array to the `is_page` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

```
<?php 
if ( is_page([3,4]) ) :
 get_header('BLACK');
else :
 get_header();
endif;
wp_head();
?>
```

& (downvote received?) if anyone's wondering why I posted the OR operator first, it's because the question presents code which doesn't demonstrate an understanding of how PHP works.

So learning PHP operators & the basics of procedural programming would be my first recommendation for this user.

Comment: It's not about the "or" it's because you copied my comment to your answer without even giving credit. You posted the answer with "or" at the same time as I posted a comment with "array". I then reconsidered, and made it an answer. Six minutes later you add "array" to your answer.

Comment: Didn't even notice your answer before amending mine. Scouts's honour. I've been building with WordPress since 2.8, took 1.5 years off to work with Laravel. I reconsidered my answer as I walked away from my desk. Answer took me a while to type because I was doing other things simultaneously. Honestly didn't see your answer until after I noticed the downvote. What's your time zone? I'm pst

Comment: Both answers were great and gave me a nice insight into PHP. The "OR" operator gave me a better example of how the 'OR' operator functions, but both are great and thank you!

Comment: Very welcome @HarisMustajbasic Another technique which may help is using `is_page_template` instead of `is_page` that will let you add modify output based on the page's assigned page-template, rather than it's unique id; which can be good for maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used WordPress but it seems is_page accepts array.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

```
if(is_page(array(3,4,5))) { 
     get_header('BLACK');
}else {
     get_header();
}
wp_head();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have page ID 3, 4, 5 these types of condition will be ok, but if you have 10, 20 pages then, what will you do ? You will keep on adding conditions ? So, best option in such cases is to create page templates, and add conditions.

Create any page templates, eg. `black-logo-template.php`

```
<?php 
if(is_page_template( 'black-logo-template.php' )) {
 get_header('BLACK');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>
```

Comment: Nice! I was planning to use only three pages on my website, but this will definitely come handy to me if I will need to use more. Thanks a lot!